Failed building wheel for glpk
I am trying to install the glpk library for PYOMO optimization.
I am using Python 3.12.2 in Visual Studiuo on MacOS 14.3.1
If I try to install glpk like
pip install glpk

It gives the following error:
Collecting glpk
Downloading glpk-0.4.7.tar.gz (161 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 161.2/161.2 kB 5.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: glpk
Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[31 lines of output\]
WARNING setuptools_scm.pyproject_reading toml section missing 'pyproject.toml does not contain a tool.setuptools_scm section'
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'glpk' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src
clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DVERSION_NUMBER="0.4.7" -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c src/2to3.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/2to3.o
clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DVERSION_NUMBER="0.4.7" -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c src/bar.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/bar.o
src/bar.c:213:8: warning: assigning to 'char \*' from 'const char \*' discards qualifiers \[-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers\]
name = PyString_AsString(value);
^ \~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
src/bar.c:215:7: error: call to undeclared function 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations \[-Wimplicit-function-declaration\]
if (PyString_Size(value) \> 255) {
^
src/2to3.h:13:26: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_Size'
#define PyString_Size(o) PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(o)
^
src/bar.c:215:7: note: did you mean 'PyDict_GET_SIZE'?
src/2to3.h:13:26: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_Size'
#define PyString_Size(o) PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(o)
^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:53:26: note: 'PyDict_GET_SIZE' declared here
static inline Py_ssize_t PyDict_GET_SIZE(PyObject \*op) {
^
src/bar.c:381:9: warning: initializing 'char \*' with an expression of type 'const char \*' discards qualifiers \[-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers\]
char \*sstr = PyString_AsString(value);
^      \~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk
Failed to build glpk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
federicoravazzolo@Federicos-MacBook-Pro Documents % pip install glpk-5.0.tar.gz  
Processing ./glpk-5.0.tar.gz
ERROR: file:///Users/federicoravazzolo/Documents/glpk-5.0.tar.gz does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
federicoravazzolo@Federicos-MacBook-Pro Documents % pip install glpk  
Collecting glpk
Using cached glpk-0.4.7.tar.gz (161 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: glpk
Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[31 lines of output\]
WARNING setuptools_scm.pyproject_reading toml section missing 'pyproject.toml does not contain a tool.setuptools_scm section'
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'glpk' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src
clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DVERSION_NUMBER="0.4.7" -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c src/2to3.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/2to3.o
clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DVERSION_NUMBER="0.4.7" -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c src/bar.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/bar.o
src/bar.c:213:8: warning: assigning to 'char \*' from 'const char \*' discards qualifiers \[-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers\]
name = PyString_AsString(value);
^ \~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
src/bar.c:215:7: error: call to undeclared function 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations \[-Wimplicit-function-declaration\]
if (PyString_Size(value) \> 255) {
^
src/2to3.h:13:26: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_Size'
#define PyString_Size(o) PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(o)
^
src/bar.c:215:7: note: did you mean 'PyDict_GET_SIZE'?
src/2to3.h:13:26: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_Size'
#define PyString_Size(o) PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(o)
^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:53:26: note: 'PyDict_GET_SIZE' declared here
static inline Py_ssize_t PyDict_GET_SIZE(PyObject \*op) {
^
src/bar.c:381:9: warning: initializing 'char \*' with an expression of type 'const char \*' discards qualifiers \[-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers\]
char \*sstr = PyString_AsString(value);
^      \~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk
Failed to build glpk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


For macox...  brew install glpk
